# Let $(V,\left \langle .,. \right \rangle)$ be a space of Hilbert and $F\in V'$. Then $U=\{v\in V: F(v)=0\}$ is a closed subspace of $V$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

**Let $(V,\left \langle .,. \right \rangle)$ be a space of Hilbert and $F\in V'$. Then $U=\{v\in V: F(v)=0\}$ is a closed subspace of $V$.**

I have thought of doing the following: Let's take $\{x_n\}_n\subset U$ a sequence and prove that $x_n\to x$ in $U$. Note that $F(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $F(x_n)\to 0$. But I don't know how to prove that $\{x_n\}_n$ converges and that this limit is an element of $U$, any idea? Thank you!

Comment: "I don't know how to prove that $\{x_n\}_n$ converges"... You assume *yourself* that it converges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way is to see that $U=F^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\{0\}$ is a closed set and the pre-image of a closed set of a continuity map is still closed.

Comment: Why is $F$ continuous? I only know that $F:V\to \mathbb{R}$ is linear and bounded.

Comment: For linear functional, boundedness and continuity are equivalent, this is a good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to prove that $(x_n)$ converges. To prove that $U$ is closed you have to take sequence $x_n$ in $U$ which converges to some $u$ and then  prove that $u \in U$. This is obvious from continuity of $F$. Convergence is given to you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever $T : X\to Y$ is a bounded operator between normed spaces, then $\ker T$ is closed. Proof: Let $x_n\in\ker T$ such that $x_n\to x$. Then, by continuity of $T$, we have $Tx = \lim_nTx_n = 0$. So, $x\in\ker T$.

A bounded linear functional is just a special case of a bounded operator.

Comment: Why is $F$ continuous? I only know that $F:V\to \mathbb{R}$ is linear and bounded.

Comment: Well, what is $V'$? Usually, it is the set of all bounded linear functionals. Boundedness is equivalent to continuity for linear maps. If $V'$ is just the set of linear functionals on $V$, then the claim is false. There exist unbounded (and thus non-continuous) linear functionals. And for these the kernel is NOT closed.